# Looking for a Batch Script that will combine 2 file types with the same name into 1 zip file

Tags: windows, batch, 7-zip

I have 2200 files.

```
E:\Saturn Bins and Cues\(Files are here)

aaa.bin
aaa.cue
bbb.bin
bbb.cue
ccc.bin
ccc.cue

Etc
```

Looking for a batch script that will make a 7z or zip file and combine the bins and cues with the same name.

This is what I got so far. I know it isnt right, so how can I fix this.

Thank you for your time. (7z is installed but if I have to move the contents over to the E drive, I will)

```
@ECHO OFF
PATH=C:\Program Files\7-Zip
FOR %F IN ("E:\Saturn Bins and Cues") DO 7Z a "%~nF.zip" "%~nF.bin" "%~nF.cue"
```

Comment: `"%PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "cue.7z" "E:\Saturn Bins and Cues\*.cue"`

Comment: `"%PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "bin.7z" "E:\Saturn Bins and Cues\*.bin"`

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /D C:\so\1503595\files
for %%e in ("*.bin") do (..\7-Zip\7z.exe a "%%~ne.zip" "%%~ne.bin" "%%~ne.cue")
```

This should work for you.

Since the cue and bin files have the same name, i first find every ".bin" file and use its name without the extension (by using ~n inside the %%e it will set it to file name only - use "help for" on cmd for more details on this).

Then i simply add the files to a zip with the same name.